# How to change the Nautilus keyboard shortcut for changing tabs?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I'm looking for a way to change the keyboard shortcut for changing tabs
from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I think it's a very common and useful shortcut and I was surprised to discover it isn't include in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor.

Comment: I Didn't know that. I'm used to it from windows, [ctrl][tab] works on every thing. I think that for now I will be satisfied if it worked on nautilus firs.

Comment: I see, I didn't understand it untill now. If you now of a way to change this in Nautilus I will be grateful.

Comment: FYI, Ctrl+PageUp/Down and Ctrl+Tab only allows you to switch between tabs on a browser in Windows. You need to edit your question as to what tabs of which specific program you want to modify the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: That isn't true Ctrl+Tab works all most on every thing in windows. And I'm looking for a modification for Nautilus.